# How to say if meta_value is greater than 0 in an array?

Tags: php, array

Right now I have this:

```
$args  = array(
    'meta_key' => 'userfunds',
    'meta_value' => '0',    
);
```

Basically this will show users who have exactly '0' as `meta_value`.

How do I say that `meta_value` has to be greater than '0'?

I have tried:

```
    'meta_value' > '0',
```

But using the above, it shows all users, regardless of their value.

So I guess using `>` in the array is an invalid line and not what I need.

I know I'm probably missing something very small in my code?

should I use `compare`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters), you can use `meta_compare`:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'       => 'userfunds',
    'meta_value_num' => '0', 
    'meta_compare'   => '>',   
);
```

Note that I changed `meta_value` to `meta_value_num`. This ensures the values is treated as a number for the comparison. You'd probably be ok without it, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! worked like a charm!